# How to calculate MD5 in XML

Tags: xml, xslt

Is there a way to calculate MD5 for a given string in XSL without using any libraries or using FOO ?

for example :

```
<Property name = "DXE PROPERTY">
```

how to calculate the MD5 for the @name ?

Comment: In theory XSL is a Turing-complete language so everything that can be calculated can also be handled by XSL. In practice, no.

Comment: Well, if you are not willing to use extensions, you could implement the [algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Pseudocode) yourself, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add functionality. There are however projects like this one: https://github.com/rubinsztajn/xsltmd5 that add that functionality and this one: http://www.amundsen.com/blog/archives/728 that may help you.

Comment: In other words, it is not native.